# Mute Windows 10 Notification using C# or WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi

I'm currently researching on how to mute the windows 10 notification but it i havent found any concrete solution yet.

What i want to do is to disable all notifications when i press a button or check a checkbox. 
It is similar on what you do on the notification settings, but i want it to do it progmatically on my application.

I'm currently reading the document of microsoft about Notification Listener.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener

Comment: First try to do something your own and then post your question here with codes and errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciate your feedbacks! I did some tinkering and found out the service responsible for the notification. I'm not really confident that this is the best approach, but it is working for me.

What I did was I stopped the service using C#. Here is my sample code:

```
  ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();

        foreach (ServiceController service in services)
        {
            if (service.ServiceName.Contains(serviceName))
            {
                service.Start();

            }


        }
```

Here is the service responsible for the notifications:
[Notification Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMPPg.png)

I dont know if this is a good practice or not so I'm still open for feedbacks and suggestions.

Thank you!

Comment: Feel free to mark it yourself to highlight it if it really available to you. You could still re-accept it if you've got a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

NotificationListener allows you to access the notifications, but not to the configuration of the system. And you must think it's a UWP Api...
You want to do something that can not be done in UWP Api(impossible) nor WPF(possible, i wish you good luck).

You can't change system settings inside the UWP app box -safety and things-. The way to do it is "Open the Configuration App where you want **the user** make the change".

If you wan't to this in WPF/.net you'd have to play with PInvoke and WinApi seriously. And that means thinking about **privileges**, **run as admin,** find the **functions in WinApi .h files**, etc...

Keeping simple, in UWP, nope; in WPF, you have to read a lot of source code/documentation of Windows .h files, make the c# version of the structs, etc...

The real question here is... It's necessary? Windows provides Focus Assist with two clicks (corner, Focus Assist)

Comment: The Windows Runtime exposes its services using ECMA-335 conforming metadata. Accessing Windows Runtime services from C# does not require you to drop down to P/Invoke or similar interop schemes.

Comment: @IInspectable Im not sure if that allow edit system configurations. I dont know that way, sorry. But im sure uwp apis doent allow that thing. Sorry, Im on phone now

Comment: The Windows Runtime does not equate to UWP. The Windows Runtime is the foundational infrastructure for Windows to expose its API's. You can access almost the entire Windows Runtime API surface from classic Win32 applications.

Comment: @IInspectable Yeah, I know UWP isn't what are you talking about, i was just pointing. Can you give some link to docs please? I'm so interested in learn about that. It's something new for me all of this.

Comment: Is there a UI automation approach that just does the two clicks? the reason it is necessary is that you can forget to do said two clicks before a crucial meeting - thus the use case for automation.